# Least frequent words - python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-2.7

How do i Remove all special characters in the para given below and calculate the less frequently used words whose count < 3 and print the last 20 less frequent words - in python

Input

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sem odio, varius nec aliquam nec, tempor commodo ante. Pellentesque sit amet augue vel ante dictum placerat ut ut sapien. Proin maximus eu diam in posuere. Suspendisse in lectus in lectus finibus auctor. Nam sed porttitor arcu. Vestibulum augue odio, posuere quis libero sed, pharetra sollicitudin est. Donec sit amet nunc eu nisi malesuada elementum id ut purus.Nunc sit amet % massa rhoncus, venenatis eros sit amet, ornare augue. Nunc a mi sed est tincidunt facilisis at nec diam. Donec nec ex lorem. Morbi vitae diam tincidunt, dignissim arcu ut, facilisis nisi. Maecenas non felis #ullamcorper, viverra augue id, consequat_nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Proin tempor, sapien ut ornare placerat, sapien mauris luctus sapien, eget aliquam turpis urna at quam. Sed a&eros vel@ ante vestibulum vulputate. Suspendisse vitae vulputate velit. Suspendisse! ligula nisl, semper ut sodales et, ultricies porttitor felis. Nunc ac mattis erat, aliquet pretium risus. Nullam quis congue lacus, et mollis nulla. Nunc laoreet in nisi sit amet facili*sis. Cras rutrum justo ut eros mollis volutpat. Sed quis mi nunc. Nunc sed bibendum nibh, quis bibendum tortor.

Expected result:

['ultricies', 'ac', 'mattis', 'erat', 'aliquet', 'pretium', 'risus', 'Nullam', 'congue', 'lacus', 'mollis', 'nulla', 'laoreet', 'Cras', 'rutrum', 'justo', 'volutpat', 'bibendum', 'nibh', 'tortor']

i tried:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

from collections import Counter

def stringmethod(para, special1, special2, list1, strfind):
    # Write your code here
    word1=para
    for char in special1:
        word1 = word1.replace(char,"")

    word1=str(word1)
    slist=word1.split()

    c = Counter(slist).most_common()[-20:]
    lst=[]
    for i in range(0,len(c)):
        l1,l2=c[i]
        lst.append(l1)
    
    print(lst)


if __name__ == '__main__':
```

and i get

```
['semper', 'sodales', 'ultricies', 'ac', 'mattis', 'erat', 'aliquet', 'pretium', 'risus', 'Nullam', 'congue', 'lacus', 'nulla', 'laoreet', 'Cras', 'rutrum', 'justo', 'volutpat', 'nibh', 'tortor']
```

instead of

```
['ultricies', 'ac', 'mattis', 'erat', 'aliquet', 'pretium', 'risus', 'Nullam', 'congue', 'lacus', 'mollis', 'nulla', 'laoreet', 'Cras', 'rutrum', 'justo', 'volutpat', 'bibendum', 'nibh', 'tortor']
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I get `['semper', 'sodales', 'ultricies', 'ac', 'mattis', 'erat', 'aliquet', 'pretium', 'risus', 'Nullam', 'congue', 'lacus', 'nulla', 'laoreet', 'Cras', 'rutrum', 'justo', 'volutpat', 'nibh', 'tortor'] 
` ... how do you determine which ones to use?

Comment: i get the same too... but the online test fails me and expects the expected result i gave above

Comment: The expected output seems just wrong to me, so I'd contact whoever is administering the assignment and tell them that you stand by your result that the test says is wrong. It's expecting you to include `'bibendum'` and `'mollis'`, but those each occur more often (twice) than a whole lot of other words. Even without that specific error, when there are 60-ish words each used only once in a paragraph, the set of the 20 least-used is under-specified.

Answer (score 2):

To remove all special characters in the given para:

```
word=""
for ch in para:
    if ch.isalnum() or ch==" ":
        word+=ch
```

To calculate the less frequently used words whose count < 3:

```
x=[]
for i in word.split():
    if  word.split().count(i)<3 and i not in x:
        x.append(i)
```

To print the last 20 less frequent words:

```
    print(x[-20:])
```

It works perfectly fine:)

Answer (score 0):

The splitting/removing can be done using `re`gex, counting can be done with `collections.Counter.most_common()` in 2 lines like so:

```
t =("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
    "Aliquam sem odio, varius nec aliquam nec, tempor commodo "
    "ante. Pellentesque sit amet augue vel ante dictum placerat"
    " ut ut sapien. Proin maximus eu diam in posuere. "
    "Suspendisse in lectus in lectus finibus auctor. Nam sed " 
    "porttitor arcu. Vestibulum augue odio, posuere quis libero"
    " sed, pharetra sollicitudin est. Donec sit amet nunc eu "
    "nisi malesuada elementum id ut purus.Nunc sit amet % massa"
    " rhoncus, venenatis eros sit amet, ornare augue. Nunc a mi"
    " sed est tincidunt facilisis at nec diam. Donec nec ex lorem."
    " Morbi vitae diam tincidunt, dignissim arcu ut, facilisis "
    "nisi. Maecenas non felis #ullamcorper, viverra augue id, "
    "consequat_nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Proin tempor, sapien "
    "ut ornare placerat, sapien mauris luctus sapien, eget aliquam"
    " turpis urna at quam. Sed a&eros vel@ ante vestibulum vulputate."
    " Suspendisse vitae vulputate velit. Suspendisse! ligula nisl, "
    "semper ut sodales et, ultricies porttitor felis. Nunc ac mattis"
    " erat, aliquet pretium risus. Nullam quis congue lacus, et mollis"
    " nulla. Nunc laoreet in nisi sit amet facili*sis. Cras rutrum justo"
    " ut eros mollis volutpat. Sed quis mi nunc. Nunc sed bibendum nibh,"
    " quis bibendum tortor.")

from collections import Counter 
import re

c = Counter((w for w in re.split("[ .,]",t) if re.match(r"^[a-zA-Z]+$", w)))
print([w for w,cnt in c.most_common() if cnt < 3][-20:])
```

which gives:

```
['semper', 'sodales', 'ultricies', 'ac', 'mattis', 'erat', 'aliquet', 'pretium', 
 'risus', 'Nullam', 'congue', 'lacus', 'nulla', 'laoreet', 'Cras', 'rutrum', 'justo',
 'volutpat', 'nibh', 'tortor']
```

These are the 20 words occuring 1 time total *in reverse order of occurence*.

The total things occuring once are:

```
print([w for w,cnt in c.most_common() if cnt == number])
['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit', 'Aliquam',
 'sem', 'varius', 'commodo', 'Pellentesque', 'vel', 'dictum', 'maximus', 
 'finibus', 'auctor', 'Nam', 'Vestibulum', 'libero', 'pharetra', 
 'sollicitudin', 'malesuada', 'elementum', 'purus', 'massa', 'rhoncus', 
 'venenatis', 'a', 'ex', 'lorem', 'Morbi', 'dignissim', 'Maecenas', 'non', 
 'viverra', 'potenti', 'mauris', 'luctus', 'eget', 'turpis', 'urna', 'quam',
 'vestibulum', 'velit', 'ligula', 'nisl', 'semper', 'sodales', 'ultricies', 
 'ac', 'mattis', 'erat', 'aliquet', 'pretium', 'risus', 'Nullam', 'congue', 
 'lacus', 'nulla', 'laoreet', 'Cras', 'rutrum', 'justo', 'volutpat', 'nibh', 
 'tortor']
```

The site seems to want a special fraction of those that do not involve first-first or last-first nor alphabetically sorted - so to fix your "task" you need to get behind what criteria they use to *choose* from above list.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, let me optimize a line of your code.

```
def stringmethod(para, special1, special2, list1, strfind):
    # Remove special characters from para and add the new string to word1. 
    word1=para.translate({ord(c): None for c in special1})
```

Ok, now onto the problem... the issue lies on the understanding of the phrase "less frequent", which is not the same as "least frequent", specially when your main instruction add the count<3 filter.

Think about it like this, if the request is the last record of less frequent words in a text which count<3, from which you get a dictionary like this:

```
Original: {'pear': 1, 'apple': 2, 'red': 3}
Original after filter count<3: {'pear': 1, 'apple': 2}

Less used:
    'apple':2 is part of the less used group, and is the last record

Least used:
    {'apple': 2, 'pear': 1} - Ordered to reflect usage
    'pear': 1 - is the last record, on the LEAST used word group.
```

Try the following function - it will return a list with every word, in order of appearance which has a count less than 3 (2 and 1).

```
def word_count(str):
    counts = dict()
    words = str.split()
    for word in words:
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1
    d=dict((k, v) for k,v in counts.items() if v<3)
    return list(d)[-20:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word1 = para

for x in special1:
    word1 = word1.replace(x, '')    

 repwords = word1.split()

wordfreq = []
for w in repwords:
    if (repwords.count(w) < 3 and w not in wordfreq):
        wordfreq.append(w)

print(wordfreq[-20:])
```

Comment: @sudheer, you need to provide more information on your answer. Explaining the code will help others understanding your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def stringmethod(para, special1, special2, list1, strfind):
    # Write your code here
    word1 =''.join(x for x in para if x not in special1)
    rword2 = word1[0:70][::-1]
    print(rword2)
    print(special2.join(rword2.replace(' ','')))
    if all(x in para for x in list1):
        print('Every string in {} were present'.format(list1))
    else:
        print('Every string in {} were not present'.format(list1))
    print(word1.split()[0:20])
    
    w = ''
    
    for x in word1:
        if not x.isdigit():
            w +=x
    
    x = []
    for i in w.split():
        if w.split().count(i) <3 and i not in x:
            x.append(i)
    
    print(x[-20:])
    
    print(word1.rindex(strfind))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for myChar in special1:
    para = para.replace(myChar,"")
word1=para
rword2=word1[69::-1]
print(rword2)
myspaceremove=rword2.replace(" ", "")
myspaceremove=myspaceremove.replace("  ", "")
myword= special2.join(myspaceremove)
print(myword)
if all(SearchStr in para for SearchStr in list1):
    print("Every string in  %s were present" %list1)
else:
    print("Every string in  %s were not present" %list1)
number=word1
splitAll = number.split()
print(splitAll[0:20])
mylist=[]
myDict = dict()
for t in splitAll:
    myDict[t]=myDict.get(t,0)+1
for x,y in myDict.items():
    if(y<3):
        mylist.append(x)
print(mylist[-20:])

print(word1.rindex(strfind))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
x =[]
counts=Counter(word1.split())
for i in word1.split():
    if counts[i]<3 and i not in x: 
         x.append(i)
print(x[-20:])
```

Try this, it worked for me.